# Firebase analytics cookies are not Secure

Tags: firebase, security, cookies, google-analytics, samesite

Background: browsers are going to apply policy to reject cookies which have SameSite=none without Secure attribute. We are trying to set SameSite=none;Secure for all cookies (unless they already are Lax or Strict) we have to ensure we will keep the same behavior after policies will be applied.

What I understand, Firebase analytics uses Google analytics under the hood, and that's why by using Firebase analytics I have _ga* cookies. By default they does not get Secure cookie attribute. I've tried to make it secure by calling

```
gtag('config', <id>, {
  cookie_flags: 'secure;samesite=none'
});
```

right after the

```
firebase.analytics();
```

Couldn't find another way to configure it for Firebase cookies.

In the result I get 'Secure' for _ga* when checking site's cookies.
But in Firefox I get a warning that _ga* cookies are without Secure attribute and will be rejected soon.
I don't get such warning in Google Chrome though, even I enabled flags for new SameSite features.

I suspect they are set without Secure attribute, the warning is generated, and then after calling gtag() they become Secure.

Questions:

- Am I doing it in the right way?
- Does this warning in Firefox means there's still a problem with insecure cookies?
- Why I don't get warning in Google Chrome?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same issue

Comment: @RamKumar I don't remember for sure how we ended up with this. Perhaps we left it as it is, since we see 'Secure' tag in cookies.
This piece was set for this issue too, but don't remember if it was the solution:
ga('create', <reducted>, 'auto', { 'cookieFlags': 'SameSite=None; Secure' });
If you try, please post here the results.